# How to install netpbm header files?

Tags: compiling

I want to compile some C programs that use the netpbm functions.  They need the file "netpbm/pnm.h".  How do I install this file?  It seems that netpbm is already installed, but the header files are not installed.

I've been using the redhat version of linux for a long time, but I am new to ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu, `pnm.h` appears to be provided by either the `libnetpbm9-dev` or `libnetpbm10-dev`, however the path to the file is `/usr/include/pnm.h` rather than `/usr/include/netpbm/pnm.h` so you may need to modify the `#include` directives in your program's source code.

For future reference, you can search package contents online at http://packages.ubuntu.com/ or by installing the `apt-file` utility and querying its package database for matching filenames e.g.

```
~$ apt-file search '/pnm.h'
libitpp-dev: /usr/include/itpp/srccode/pnm.h
libnetpbm10-dev: /usr/include/pnm.h
libnetpbm9-dev: /usr/include/pnm.h
```